# Can anyone explain this nested each behavior to me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="img-container">8
    <div class="product">
        <ul class="sizeAvail" style="display:none;">
            <li><a href="one"></a>7</li>
            <li><a href="one"></a>7</li>
            <li><a href="one"></a>7</li>
            <li><a href="one"></a>7</li>
            <li><a href="one"></a>7</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="imgblock">7
    <div class="product">
        <ul class="sizeAvail" style="display:none;">
            <li><a href="one"></a>8</li>
            <li><a href="one"></a>8.5</li>
            <li><a href="one"></a>9</li>
            <li><a href="one"></a>9.5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="imagearea">6
    <div class="product">
        <ul class="sizeAvail" style="display:none;">
            <li>7</li>
            <li>6.5</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and here's the javascript:

```
$(".img-container").each(function(){
$(".product").each(function () {
    $(".sizeAvail li").each(function () {
            $(this).parent().show();
    });
});
```

});

I was expecting to get something like this, for only the first div since it's the only div with a class match:

8
7
7
7
7
7

But I got this .. essentially the nested each functions running on all divs:
8
7
7
7
7
7
7
8
8.5
9
9.5
6
7
6.5
7
8

Here's the link to a jFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TGXsk/7/

My actual ultimate goal is to get all href values but I was working my way up to it and got stuck.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `$(".product")` will return all three div tags (not only the one inside your div tag with the class img-container. I would consider to move all selectors into one statement.

Comment: If your goal is to get all href values, you can select all the `<a>` tags with a single selector, including only those a tags inside a specific parent or parents.  For instance, $('div.product a') will select every link inside a .product div.  You can then use the .each() method on this set to do something with every href attribute.

Comment: @SurrealDreams there's no manipulation based on `<a>` tags here, just `<li>`

Comment: @SetSailMedia I realize that, but OP noted at the end of his question that his ultimate goal was to get href values.  That's why I commented instead of answering.  Your answer is correct, and addresses the question as asked.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Surreal Dreams! It's a helpful pointer to a struggling noob in addition to the answers provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript is no different than:

```
$(".sizeAvail li").each(function () {
    $(this).parent().show();
});
```

Except that it's doing that repeatedly due to being within nested loops.

If you want specifically to search within the scope of the previous loops you need to add the [selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context).

```
$(".img-container").each(function () {
    $(".product", $(this)).each(function () {
        $(".sizeAvail li", $(this)).each(function () {
            $(this).parent().show();
        });
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TGXsk/10/

Comment: Great link to the selector context info in addition to the answer PLUS fiddle. That selector context info really helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

your nested `.each()` aren't actually doing anything to filter your selection. You need a `$(this).` to locate just those children of the parent.

```
$(".img-container").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".product").each(function () {
        $(this).find(".sizeAvail li").each(function () {
            $(this).parent().show();
        });
    });

});
```

In your example, you're essentially running nested `for () loop` across all elements.

Comment: thanks very much! These answers were also really helpful in clarifying use of "this" for me. As a noob I was getting confused, especially in the context of nested each loops.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(".img-container").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".product").each(function () {
        $(this).find(".sizeAvail li").each(function () {
            $(this).parent().show();
         });
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TGXsk/8/)

Comment: This answer, along with the others, reminds me of two things:

1) I have a LOT to learn. :-)
2) There are a LOT of great folks out on the Net who are willing to help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong here. In you code:

```
$(".img-container").each(function(){/* Select all elements with "img-container" class */
  $(".product").each(function () {/* Select all elements with "product" class (not only child of "img-container" div ) */
     $(".sizeAvail li").each(function () {/* Select all child li elements with-in "sizeAvail" class */
            $(this).parent().show();
     });
  });
});
```

As you mentioned :  you only want to show first div which have "img-container", so for this you need to modify your code like this -

```
$(".img-container .product .sizeAvail li").each(function(){
   $(this).parent().show();
});
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TGXsk/12/)

Comment: Ultimately, I want to be able to run the loops across all matching nested elements (I wasn't clear about that) .. but your answer made perfect sense. Thanks!